# $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n+3}$, sum, area of convergence & center

Tags: calculus

I want to find the

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n+3}$$

now this is how I thought about doing it but I get stuck.

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ given that absolute value of x is less then zero.

$$\int x^n \, dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

I keep integrating the result until I get
$$\frac{x^{n+3}}{(n+3) (n+1) (n+2)}=\frac{3 x^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log (1-x)-\frac{x}{2}+x \log (1-x)-\frac{1}{2} \log (1-x)$$

I thought about multiplying by $$\frac{(n+1) (n+2)}{x^3}$$

However, the answer should be this: $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n+3}=-\frac{\log (1-x)}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2 x}$$

On the interval [-1,1), and $\frac{1}{3}$ if x=0.

Could someone please show me what I did wrong and how the steps should be to get the correct answer?

Comment: What did you integrate to get the right hand side of the equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I approached it in a slightly different way using Taylor expansions.

The sum for $x=0$ is trivial.

For $x \in (-1,1)$
$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\dots$$
$$-\log(1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\dots$$
$$-\log(1-x)-x-\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\dots$$
$$-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\dots = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n+3}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good way of handling these series:

Let $s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{n+3}$ (defined for $|x|<1$). Then
$$
x^3s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n+3}}{n+3},
$$
and hence
$$
(x^3s(x))'=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^{n+2}=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n=\frac{x^2}{1-x}.
$$
Integrating from $0$ to $t$, we get
$$
t^3s(t)-0^3s(0)=\int_0^t\frac{x^2}{1-x}\,dx = -t-\frac{t^2}{2}-\log(1-t),
$$
so (switching back to $x$ as variable)
$$
s(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x^3}.
$$